# Pattern Recognition Challenge

Tags: python, design-patterns, scikit-learn, anaconda

I will state up front, I am not a Data Scientist, but have the wherewithal to learn what I need to know. However, I need advice as to where to look and the appropriate algorithms to study.

The problem as as follows. I have 10 years of 1 hour observations of output from a sensor. For the argument, let's use the output of a Weather Station and more specifically, a solar panel, in the form of a float in milliVolts.

You might argue that if a 24 Hour subset of data from this Time Series (24 Points) were taken as a matrix for comparison to the historical Time Series, one could identify "sunny" days in the past. If we were to take the latest 24 hrs of data as a comparison, we might be able to identify days that were "similar" to today and thereby taking the next subsequent matrix from a matched position, "predict" what is going to happen tomorrow, from historical action.

This is of course a rough analogy, but illustrates my problem.

I wish to take an arbitrary 24 hr period from the Time Series (Lets call this Matrix a) and identify from the Time Series (000s of Matrices) those 24 hr periods that are similar.

I have reviewed a lot around this subject in the form of various types of Regression and at one stage identified that the Data Compression algorithms would be the most effective, if you could source the subsequent dictionary made from the process, however, I realised the matching in this case is "exact" and I wish for "similar".

I have settled on what I believe to be correct, "L1 Penalty and Sparsity in Logistic Regression" located [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_logistic_l1_l2_sparsity.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-logistic-l1-l2-sparsity-py).

Where I (if I understand correctly) take a comparison Matrix, compare it to others and get a score for "similarity" (In this case called C). From here I can carry on with my experiment.

If some kind hearted Data Scientist might me a favor and 1. Confirm my direction effective or, if not 2. Point me to where I might find the process to answer my problem, I would be eternally grateful.

Many thanks in advance

ApteryxNZ

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so before posting your next question here.

Comment: For specific questions about modeling strategies, you might consider asking a specific question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  Although you reference `sklearn` here, you haven't really formulated enough a specific question about coding to make this post appropriate for StackOverflow.  I'd suggest you start by working through the many available tutorials online for LASSO regularization and logistic regression, if that's your focus.  If you have specific questions, come back and post them here.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice and my apologies for any transgression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For timeseries forecasting (prediction), you can search about LSTM neural network, SVM and even MLP. I've seen timeseries forecasting with simpler classifiers, such as AODE.

To filter the data (if applicable) that you will input to your timeseries you can search about Granger causality, Particle Sworm optimizations and even genetic algorithms

For finding similar patterns in the timeseries, I think your best option is using Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) used for speech recognition

You can search about related work in some journals such as:

- Pattern Recognition Letters
- Pattern Recognition
- Neurocomputing
- Applied Soft Computing
- Information Sciences
- Machine Learning
- Neural Networks
- IEEE Transaction on Neural Networks and Learning Systems

Comment: Thank you for the time you have taken to respond.  I will study these and come back with specific programming questions If needed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this really depends how you define "similar".

One simple way would be the "nearest neighbors" approach: treat your data points as 24-dimensional vectors, then find the ones with the shortest Euclidean (or Manhattan or…) distance to your goal point. Those are the most similar days. (k-d trees can speed up this process significantly.)

But, 24 dimensions might be too much for your purposes. Principal Component Analysis (PCA) can reduce them from 24-dimensional points to some lower number of dimensions, while preserving the variation as much as possible. Then finding the closest points will be much faster.

Note that both of these methods will only work if you're comparing value-by-value, that is, if you don't consider "the same but one hour later" to be particularly similar.

Comment: Many thanks Draconis. I appreciate the response and information.